# Bash script for nagios to monitor error in logs within last 'n' minutes

Tags: linux, bash, nagios

I've written a bash script for nagios to look into a logs file based on a certain time stamp format and search for a string.  The script is supposed to return the number of errors found in the last "n" minutes. To do so I'm using a grep with --date="-10 min ". Now this will look at the error log 10 minutes ago and return an error based on the logic provided. Because I want to check everything starting with 10 minutes ago I'm using a for loop, the only problem is that I cannot reset the variable and I could't find any solution for this. Already googled and tried var=, var="", unset var etc. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated, please see the script below.

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG_FILE=$1
ERROR_MESSAGE=$2
TIME_SPAN=$3
WARNING_THRESHOLD=$4
CRITICAL_THRESHOLD=$5

for (( i = $TIME_SPAN;  i >= 0; --i )); do
   TIME_SPAN=$i
   echo "$TIME_SPAN"
   GET_ERRORS=`grep "$(date +'%d %b %Y %H:%M' --date="-$TIME_SPAN min")" $LOG_FILE |  grep -oi "\($ERROR_MESSAGE\)" -wc`
   let COUNT=COUNT+GET_ERRORS
   GET_ERRORS=""
done



if [ "$COUNT" -lt "$WARNING_THRESHOLD" ]; then
    echo "OK - $COUNT errors found in: $LOG_FILE"
    exit 0
elif [[ ( "$COUNT" -ge "$WARNING_THRESHOLD" ) && ( "$COUNT" -lt "$CRITICAL_THRESHOLD" ) ]]; then
    echo "WARNING - $COUNT errors found in: $LOG_FILE"
    exit 1
elif [ "$COUNT" -ge "$CRITICAL_THRESHOLD" ]; then
    echo "CRITICAL - $COUNT errors found in: $LOG_FILE"
    exit 2
fi
```

**UPDATE**

I have found the bug. Was decrementing only $i whereas I should've decrement $time_span as well. I took the liberty to change the title of the topic and add the full functional code as this script might be used by others to monitor logs in the last 'n' of minutes. I could't find anything similar in the nagios exchange.

Many thanks for your feedback!
Kind regards,
Ioan

Comment: can you add a snippet of you log?

Comment: Why do you need to clear the variable at all? It gets assigned a new value in the next iteration of the loop anyway.

Comment: Below is a line of code. @choroba it doesn't get a new value at each iteration. It seems that the value when it first runs gets added on each iteration. For example if in the first iteration the value returned is zero, then it will return zero. However, if the value is 10 and it iterates 4 times, it will return 40. This is the reason why I'm trying to find a solution to reset the variable.

Comment: @Tiago [26 Jun 2014 11:28:33,XXX] [StandardMessageDecoder-1234567] [ERROR] some other text

Comment: FYI: You can edit your question to add the log-snippet. Just click on the _[edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24429906/edit)_ link on the left side right beneath the question